# the local extrema and the saddle point - i could not find the critical points

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization

$$y=(e^y)-(ye^x)$$
I want to find the local extrema and the saddle point, what should I do?
i could not find the critical points.
what can I do?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you sure there are any critical points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What one can do in a situation like this is to try and prove that no critical points exist, thus ending the search to find them.  I proceed in this direction as follows:

We may differentiate the equation

$y = e^y - ye^x \tag 1$

with respect to $x$, to obtain

$y' = e^y y' - y'e^x - ye^x, \tag 2$

whence

$y' - e^yy' + e^x y' = -ye^x, \tag 3$

or

$(1 - e^y + e^x)y' = -ye^x, \tag 4$

from which we may isolate $y'$:

$y' = -\dfrac{ye^x}{1 - e^y + e^x}; \tag 5$

it follows from this equation that

$y' = 0 \Longleftrightarrow ye^x = 0; \tag 6$

since

$\forall x \in \Bbb R, \; e^x \ne 0, \tag 7$

we see that

$y' = 0 \Longleftrightarrow y = 0; \tag 8$

however, setting $y = 0$ in (1) yields

$0 = e^0 - 0(e^x) = e^0 = 1, \tag 9$

a contradiction from which we conclude that

$y'(x) \ne 0,\; \forall x \in \Bbb R; \tag{10}$

thus the function $y$ implicitly defined by (1) has no critical points, making moot the question of the existence of extrema or inflection (saddle) points.